# Stanford OpenIE with Pronoun Coreference Option

Tags: stanford-nlp

I was trying to run the OpenIE module through command line with the resolve_coref option, but was getting the following error:

```
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator tokenize
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator ssplit
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator pos
Reading POS tagger model from edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger ... done [0.8 sec].
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator lemma
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator depparse
Loading depparse model file: edu/stanford/nlp/models/parser/nndep/english_UD.gz ...
PreComputed 100000, Elapsed Time: 2.091 (s)
Initializing dependency parser done [5.6 sec].
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator ner
Loading classifier from edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ... done [1.4 sec].
Loading classifier from edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ... done [0.6 sec].
Loading classifier from edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.conll.4class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ... done [1.2 sec].
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator entitymentions
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator coref
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: annotator "coref" requires annotator "mention"
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.construct(StanfordCoreNLP.java:375)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:139)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:135)
at edu.stanford.nlp.naturalli.OpenIE.main(OpenIE.java:697)
```

It reports requiring annotator "mention", yet it previously added another annotator "entitymentions" and there seems to be some aliases resolution issue. On the other hand, I can't find relevant information about the "mention" annotator in the documentation.

I used the following command:

```
java -Xmx20g -cp stanford-corenlp-3.6.0.jar:stanford-corenlp-3.6.0-models.jar:CoreNLP-to-HTML.xsl:slf4j-api.jar:slf4j-simple.jar edu.stanford.nlp.naturalli.OpenIE -openie.resolve_coref input.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops; this is indeed a bug. Coref was refactored fairly heavily a few times between the last release and this one, and OpenIE seems to have not kept up with the changes...

It should be fixed in the GitHub version of the code, and will hopefully be incorporated into the Maven version released soon.

Comment: Hi.. Is now fixed this problem? I have the same bug with the latest version.

Comment: Yes, this should be fixed in 3.7.0 onwards.